# How to show a column's content horizontally in Crystal Reports?

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm new to crystal reports. I'm creating a bill report for clothing store application.

I'm having data like

```
prodID prodName qty rate amount salesmanID
101      saree    1   500   500   5
108      Legging  1   500   500   7
```

I want to display report as,

```
prodID prodName qty rate amount
101      saree    1   500   500
108      Legging  1   500   500
sid : 5   7
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In short: use shared variables to collect the salespersonIds within the detail section of your report, and print content of the shared variable at the end of it.

In detail:

Add one formula field to your report and drag it into the detail section. The formula should read like this (replace field name `{Befehl.salesmanID}`):

```
// @AddToArrayVar
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar array salespersonArray;
numbervar counter;
// add only new lines
if not({Befehl.salesmanID} in salespersonArray) then
(
    counter := counter + 1;
    //The line below ensures that the size of the array does
    //not exceed 1000 values. An array can contain a maximum
    //of 1000 values.
    if counter <= 1000
    then (
        Redim Preserve salespersonArray[counter];
        salespersonArray[counter] := {Befehl.salesmanID}
    )
);
```

The formula field must be part of the detail section, you can hide it via field format.

Then add a second formula field for printing the array content and place it **in a section after the details**, e.g. report footer:

```
// @PrintFromArrayVar
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar array salespersonArray;
numbervar Counter;
stringvar salespersonslist;
numbervar i;

for i := 1 to Counter do
(
    if i > 1 then salespersonslist := salespersonslist + ',';
    salespersonslist := salespersonslist + ToText(salespersonArray[i],0,'');
);

salespersonslist;
```

P.S.: I'm not sure if the 1000 item limitation is still there in current version of Crystal Reports.